# Error Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Tags: asp.net

I have a small web application. Which was working fine until I added two genericHandler in my application.

I have made the following changes for the http handler

```
 <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
        <forms protection="All" timeout="720" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" loginUrl="Login.aspx" >
        </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <httpHandlers>
        <!--Code Log Handler-->
        <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" />
        <add verb="*" type="InfoDomeNewUI.Handler.SendOWA" path="SendOWA.ashx" />
        <add verb="*" type="InfoDomeNewUI.Handler.SendSOS" path="SendSOS.ashx" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <customErrors mode="Off">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="Templates/PageNotFound.html" />
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
        <!--Code Log Handler-->
        <add name="LogHandler1" path="SendOWA.ashx" verb="*" type="InfoDomeNewUI.Handler.SendOWA"/>
        <!-- SMS SENDER-->
        <add name="SendSOS" path="SendSOS.ashx" verb="*" type="InfoDomeNewUI.Handler.SendSOS"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I am using asp.net4.0 and C#. **I am not using MVC** 
On local host it is working fine.

But when I am hosting the published code it is giving me the above error.

Stack Trace:-

> [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
>      System.Web.Http.WebHost.SuppressFormsAuthRedirectModule.Register() +0
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.Http.WebHost.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..]
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +11708830
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +465
>      System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLeve
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.Http.WebHost.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..]
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11697760
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +141
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +4866485

Comment: Installing **Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll** from nuget package, worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem. Instead of adding a class `(.cs)` file by mistake I had added a `Web API Controller` class which added a configuration file in my solution. And that configuration file was looking for the mentioned DLL (Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0.0).
It worked when I removed that file, cleaned the application and then published.

Answer (score 203):

It appears that **Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll** is not being installed in the GAC, even if .net (4.0 or 4.5 or other) are installed successfully on Windows Server. On localhost (typically Windows client), it seems like it is being in the GAC when the tools/platform (Visual Studio etc.) are installed.

As one possible fix, please try the following:

1. Run the following command in the Package Manager Console. (If you are using Visual Studio, this can be reached via menu options "Tools --> Library Package Manager --> Package Manager Console:)

   ```
   PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
   ```

   You will see the following messages if it is successfully installed.

   ```
   Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0.0'.
   Successfully added 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0.0' to Web.
   ```
2. You will notice that **Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll** has now been added as a Reference (can be seen in the references folder of your project in in Solution Explorer)
3. If you look at the properties of this reference you will notice that "**Copy Local**" has been set to "**True**" by default.
4. Now when you "Publish " your project, **Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll** will be deployed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. By your answer I was able to know that how to install a .dll in GAC. But my problem was different and I found the problem and the solution.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem! I was using a WebApi controller in my Webforms application and the deployment failed because of the mentioned error message. By adding the reference to my project and copying over the .dll, I was able to make it work.

Comment: Initially I tried going through the "Manage NuGet Packages For This Solution" interface, but it simply said that Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll was already installed, even though I couldn't see a reference to it anywhere.  By running your command line I was able to install over the top, see a reference, set to copy local, redeployed...fixed.  Thanks!!

Comment: I installed with Package Manager but it was alredy installed. But I couldn't see the Reference on the project. So I added by myself and set Copy Local to True =)

Comment: Note that in some cases you get the message "Webapp already has a reference to 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0.0'.". Use 
"Update-Package Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure -Reinstall" in those cases.

Comment: My fix for the problem was a small edit to the csproj. I added `<Private>True</Private>` inside the `<Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure">` node. This forced the dll to be copied to the output bin. The above procedures probably just make this change.

Comment: I already had it installed but 'Copy Local' was set to false. Changing it to true fixed it! Thanks

Comment: I copied Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll to bin folder then it worked.

Comment: This is the only correct answer, which is why it's upvoted so highly. Not sure why Stack Overflow is burying it.

Answer (score 19):

I installed MVC4 via WPI and it helped me.

Comment: This one worked for me as my issue was on the server but not on my machine.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem.  When I tried the accepted answer (rockyb), I got the message that the package was already installed and assigned to my project.  When I checked the references list, it was NOT referenced, however.

The Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure was installed in my solution's packages folder.  Instead of using NuGet to add the package, I just used the Add Reference option.  On the left side of the pop-up window, I chose Browse, and then pressed the Browse button on the bottom of the window.  I navigated to the packages folder under the folder that my solution was in, then drilled down to the ...\mysolution\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40 and clicked on the Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll.  After clicking OK, the package showed up in my References list.  I used the Web Deploy Package option to deploy my website and everything worked.

Comment: Money. Since this answer is so recent, and the accepted (which didn't work for me either) is so old, I assume this has something to do with an updated version of Visual Studio. Thanks!

Comment: As Robba said in a comment on a different answer, you can solve the problem of it not being in the references list (but package is installed) with: "Update-Package Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure -Reinstall".  I think that's better than browsing for the assembly.

Answer (score 9):

Why not copy Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll file manually to the server BIN folder. This works for. My project is VS2010 Website.

This file can be located:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40

Just copy and paste it in the BIN folder.

You probably need to include this in the web.config if you don't have it already

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Reference: http://thedeveloperblog.com/

Answer (score 5):

After installing Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure through `Nuget-Package Manager`

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
```

Copy the `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll` manually from the `Nuget-Package` folder on your web application and then paste it in your bin folder of your web application deployed on the web server.

> packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll

It worked for me.

Comment: Uninstall-Package Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure (then check in any changes if using Team Foundation Server) then Install-Package Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure worked for me.

Comment: sometimes hack is the only way to get a microsoft product working

Comment: This worked for me as well. yes it was a hack but it saved lots of time. how it automatically deleted from bin is mystery

Answer (score 4):

`Update-Package -reinstall Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure` didn't work for me, as I kept receiving errors that it was already installed.

I had to navigate to the *Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0* folder in the packages folder and manually delete that folder.

After doing this, running `Install-Package Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure` installed it.

Note: `CopyLocal` was automatically set to true.

Comment: didn't worked in my case. i delete infrastructure folder from packages and intalled package again

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes needs to delete the package with force then reinstall it
its works for me.
try delete package

```
Uninstall-Package Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure -force
```

then install again

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the "Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll" appeared to be missing. I have tried few advises and installed MVC`s etc. and nothing helped. The solution was to install "Web Services Enhancements (WSE) 1.0 SP1 for Microsoft .NET" which includes Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll.
Available at: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=4065

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried installing Visual Studio 2010 SP1 but it didn't worked.

Finally I get Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll from the colleague. You can find the dll into your friends PC where the project is perfectly working. Try to search dll into Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files. Go to Temp using %temp% into run window.

After getting dll into your pc, just add reference to your project and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Republishing the site fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same issue and unfortunately nothing here was working. Finally, I came across this link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jjameson/2009/11/18/the-copy-local-bug-in-visual-studio/

Turns out the solution is sort of dumb: set copy-local for the microsoft.web.infrastructure dll to False, then set it back to True.

By the way, I think what is happening is that there are two versions of the microsoft.web.infrastructure dll, one that is pre-installed in the GAC, and another one that is now a nuget package. I think one is masking the other, hence causing issues. In my particular case, on my build server, I need it to be copied over to a folder (this folder is then zipped and sent off to deployment). I guess the system had a copy locally and just thought "nah, it'll be fine"

Answer (score 0):

I have a files only website.  Added MVC 5 to webforms application (targeting net45). I had to modify the packages.config

```
package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45"
```

to

```
package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" developmentDependency="true"
```

in order for it to startup on local box in debug mode (previously had the top described error). Running VS 2017 on Windows 7...opened through File > Open > Web Site > File (chose root directory outside of IIS).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading a bunch of NuGet packages.
I have tried all kinds of deleting, cleaning, resintalling described here and beyong to no avail.  The references did not have Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure despite the NuGet manager showed it was installed.

The problem was solved by replacing:

```
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

with

```
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
```

in packages.config.  The culprit is apparently "net45".

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2022 .net.4.8

I just run this and is solved

you can install this dll using nuget package manager
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure -Version 1.0.0

Comment: Your answer contains same recommendation which most voted answer has. New answers should bring alternative / improved solution. Repeating same information is not useful. Good luck with other questions and take care!