# Why error : Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll needed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have developped a project A in C# with Visual Studio 2013.

For this project A I have no reference to Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure but a reference to another project B that references Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.

When I compile the solution, which contains both projects A and B, there is no file Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll in project A bin folder (and this is what I want).

I deployed the project A on a server and when I run this Web app on the server, I have a runtime error :

```
Unable to load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependency. The specified file cannot be found.
```

I have checked project A csproj file but there is no reference to Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.

Do you have an idea ?

Thank a lot in advance.

Eric.

Comment: If the file is needed by project B, you'll need to add that file as well. You can add the reference to the dll in proj A so that it is there when u compile it

Comment: It should be present in B and get copied to A.  [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41726487/microsoft-web-infrastructure-dll-not-found-visual-studio-2015).

Comment: Jawad, Hans Passant : thank you for your answers.
The fact is that all my projects compile well, the project A compiles without that dll.
The project A worked well before, until those runtime issues.
If that dll is only needed by B why should I add it to A ?