# Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0 Fail to load on Windows 2012 64bit, MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to upload a simple website on Windows 2012 64bit OS with Plesk installed. I use FTP publishing withing Visual studio 2013 to upload site in Virtual Directory with .NET 4.5. however I am getting

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Based on lot of threads in StackOverflow or Search, everyone is recommend to upload file in bin folder. I did that, I try it thrice as

1. Any CPU Build
2. 64bit Build
3. x86Build

But all I am getting is above error. I am using Shared hosting from local hosting provider, and hence cannot run `aspnet_regiis -i` to ensure that .net 4.5 is configured properly or not, and tech is arguing to prove/show if .net4.5 is not installed or working properly.

Any idea what and how I should be able to make it run?

EDIT: my bin folder have these files:

```
System.Web.Webpages.Razor.dll
System.Web.Webpages.dll
System.Web.Webpages.Deployment.dll
System.Web.Razor.dll
System.Web.Mvc.dll
System.Web.Helpers.dll
System.Web.Extensions.dll
System.Web.Entity.dll
System.Web.DynamicData.dll
System.Web.dll
System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll
System.EnterpriseServices.dll
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll
```

Other than project's dll

EDIT 2:

Stack Trace from error:

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.WebPages.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +0
   System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +32

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +556
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +132
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +102
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +516

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9885060
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Comment: this looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669206/error-microsoft-web-infrastructure-version-1-0-0-0-culture-neutral-publickeyt
have you tried installing the package as the answer to this suggests. You can also download the dll and manually install it in the GAC using gacutil.exe

Comment: @GearTrooper yup, I already mention that I copy those files in my BIN folder, and they are still there with all other files, for Razor and MVC.

Comment: You really should check, are there .NET 4.5 installed on the system. Without this assumption you can't really say where is the problem. Can you provide the stack trace from the exception?

Comment: @VMAtm .NET 4.5 is installed as said by tech support. I am not sure how they install, i,e. from server manager or separate setup. Add Stack trace.

Comment: Can you check, are .NET 4.5 used for Application pool your application in? Your Application could be located into Default App Pool, which can still be configured for using lower versions of the .NET

Comment: Finally tech support get it fix, they seems to mess up some configuration, they didn't tell me but it seems fixed.

Comment: I've had similar experiences in the past, and turned out that the dll was registered in the GAC, and for some reason the app chose that version over the local copy in the bin folder. Take a look at `gacutil.exe` to see if that dll is registered in the GAC.

Comment: Check the web.config for specific version?

Answer (score -1):

Files are there and environment sounds ready.

If the Application Pool has been configured as Net4.5 Integrated you should be all go.

It seems that there may be a problem in your configuration.

I propose that you install the application on a local IIS server and find out if the same error occurs.

I have had similar issues due to the application previously having been upgraded from one version of MVC to another which left traces of multiple versions of references in project files and configs.

App worked fine in dev but not on production server.

Install on local IIS server (preferably same version as your hosting provider) often makes it easier to work out the problem. If you get it running on you local IIS you are ready to work out how to do the same on the remote server. I hope you have remote IIS access which makes it easer to validate differences.